# Use Authentication (different Token) from Collection within Requests in Postman

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, postman, azure-ad-b2c

I try to create a postman collection for my backend service which uses Azure B2C Authentication.

Within my Collection I added Authentication, which works and I can authenticate within my Chrome Browser:
[image]

Once I am authenticated and redirected back to Postman it says that an `access_token` can not be found. I can see that it is in `id_token`:
[image]

Now I created also a Request with Authentication Type `oAuth 2.0` where I could select `Available Token`. But as the token is not within `access_token` it does not autofill the token. Is there any way to tell Postman that i want to use `id_token` as `access_token` within my requests in the collection?

Thanks for your help and feedback

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As you saved your token with the name as **Azure AD B2C Authentication**, for your requests, you can select the **Azure AD B2C Authentication** from your available tokens.

This will auto-fill the token

I created the token with name as **access token**

[image]

Now for my request, I selected the **access token** from the available tokens under Access Token

[image]

Then the token is auto-filled as below

[image]

In this way, you can use the Access Token in collections in postman

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the issue Token Name is just an identifier for Postman. In my 3rd screenshot I can select the Available Token, but as not within the response under `access_token` it can not find it and does not fill it out (it is within the json under `id_token`)